# Adding windows domain group to ORA_DBA not working in Oracle 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

I am running into an odd situation with adding windows domain group to **`ORA_DBA`** group to grant sysdba privileges.

I am getting an `invalid username/password - logon denied` error while connecting to an instance  in Oracle 12c.

But, if I add my individual windows account to **`ORA_DBA`** group, I am able to login just fine.

I have tried to research for an entire day but haven't had much luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> *Note* : **The windows domain group is part of the Administrator group on the server.**

This is how my `sqlnet.ora` file looks like:

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (NTS)
SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT = 120
NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH =(TNSNAMES, HOSTNAME)
NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN = WORLD
NAMES.DEFAULT_ZONE = WORLD
TRACE_LEVEL_CLIENT = OFF
AUTOMATIC_IPC = OFF
```

Comment: Need more details. Works for me (Windows 2012 R2 Domain Controller and database server, 12.1.0.2 database), see: http://pastebin.com/V1EXbbXJ All default settings.

Comment: Thanks @BalazsPapp  for testing it out. Could you please try to create a Domain group in Active Directory and adding a few users to it, and then try testing it again? I appreciate your help. Also, please let me know what more details should I include.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not possible as of now, see Oracle Support note 1065023.1: "[...] it is not possible to make a domain user member of the ORA_DBA group indirectly, via nested groups ..."

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you can't.

As part that [oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBI/user_grps.htm#CHDBEGEI) is clear, you have to be part of the `ORA_DBA` group to have the `sysdba` privilege with your Windows account. Being in a subgroup means that you have all the privileges of the parent group **without being part of it** As the same logic of oracle privileges and roles.

Comment: Thanks for your response, Walid. I am not sure if I understand what documentation you are referring. Can you please add that here?

Comment: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/NTDBI/user_grps.htm#CHDBEGEI)

Comment: Unfortunately, this documentation doesn't answer much of my question. I have already gone through this documentation twice. I appreciate it though!

Comment: Let make this clear : if i ask you this : assuming that user A is a member of subgroup that belong to ORA_DBA group, is user A a member of ORA_DBA?